I'm trying to make a geometry that looks like a mouse cursor but it looks like a triangle
I've tried changing the color function st that that divot is colored black like the background but that didnt work i dont know what else to realy do because this is my first time with sfml
code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
public:
    Player()
        : position(500,500), angle(45), array(sf::Quads, 4)
    {
        array[0].position = sf::Vector2f(0, -100);
        array[1].position = sf::Vector2f(-100, 100);
        array[2].position = sf::Vector2f(0,25);
        array[3].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 100);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < array.getVertexCount(); i++)
        {
            array[i].color = sf::Color::White;
            array[2].color = sf::Color::Black;
        }
    } 

    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        sf::Transform transform;
        transform.translate(position).rotate(angle);
        window.draw(array, transform);
    }


Please edit your question with an image of what you want and what you get.

If you set the color of each vertex, you should get a quad with a solid color.
If you set half the vertices white and the others black, you'll get a gradient between the two colors.
Your probably doesn't work as expected and with only four vertices, you might be better off to just set it directly.
array[0].position = sf::Vector2f(0, -100);
array[0].color = sf::Color::White;
array[1].position = sf::Vector2f(-100, 100);
array[1].color = sf::Color::White;
array[2].position = sf::Vector2f(0,25);
array[2].color = sf::Color::White;
array[3].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 100);
array[3].color = sf::Color::White;

Also note, that if you set it to black and your background color is black, you of course won't see anything.
